# Math to calculate percentage of ERC20 balance?

Tags: solidity

I'm trying to implement staking into a project. Lets say my contract has a balance of 1000 erc20 tokens, which during the calculation is actually 1000000000000000000000 because of wei. If i know user A has provided 255 of that 1000, user A is entitled to 25.5% of any profits. Lets pretend the profits are also 1000 eth of an erc20 token. How do I represent 25.5% since solidity only uses integers, and how do i then send 25.5% of 1000000000000000000000, which I know will not be a whole number?

Answer (score 1):

For example, you represent a percentage in the form of thousandths:

```
a_proc=(a_stake*1000)/a_sum ;
b_stake=(a_proc*b_sum)/1000 ;
```

Or directly:

```
b_stake=(a_stake*b_sum)/a_sum ;
```

You will lose the fractional part of wei, but it is a VERY small value